# query sql for mysql database

Tags: sql

Hello I have this table schema:

```
EMPLOYEE
Fname| Minit| Lname| Ssn| Bdate| Address| Sex| Salary| Super_ssn| Dno
```

The query is  the employee name, supervisor name, and employee salary for each employee.

My attempt is:

```
$SELECT Fname, Lname, Fname as SFname, Lname as SLname
FROM EMPLOYEE
$
```

It is wrong but i have no idea.
The supervisor is an employee.

Comment: "It is wrong" <---what results are you getting, and what results are you expecting?

Comment: Why is it wrong?  I do not understand what the problem is at all.

Comment: the problem is retrieve  the employee name, supervisor name, and employee salary for each employee.

Comment: @kabal, at first sight looks reasonable. Hard to debug with info provided. What error do you get? And what database are you using?

Comment: You want to do a `self join` with the table.

Comment: Sorry, i have problem to find the supervisor name (super_ssn) because it is an employee, how to do that?

Comment: I do not accept any answer because I have got -3 points for this post without any reason.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming all employees have a supervisor

```
SELECT E1.Fname As "EMP Fname", E1.Lname As "EMP Lname", E2.Fname AS "SUP Fname", E2.Lname As "SUP Lname", E1.salary
FROM EMPLOYEE E1
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE E2
ON E1.Super_ssn = E2.ssn
```

Assuming not all employees have a supervisor

```
SELECT E1.Fname As "EMP Fname", E1.Lname As "EMP Lname", E2.Fname AS "SUP Fname", E2.Lname As "SUP Lname", E1.salary
FROM EMPLOYEE E1
left join EMPLOYEE E2
on E1.Super_ssn = E2.ssn
```

The Second query wil work regardless, it just takes into account an employee without a supervisor

---

corrected my error from the comments, Thank you for finding the typo

Comment: That's how it should be. Consider providing some column alias for better readability. Also, I think you meant to say `ON E1.Super_ssn = E2.ssn`

Comment: Fixed, thank you for the correction

Comment: I added Column alliases to hopefulyl make things clearer

Comment: @kabal - what this is doing, is grabbing data from the employee table, and joining it with other information from the same table.  Looking at the select statement, you'll see the E1 prefixes are pulling data for the employee, whereas the E2 prefixes are pulling information for the supervisor.  The join statement at the end is what gets matched between the table and the duplicate copy of the table.  End result will be data rows that return the employee's first and last name, as well as their supervisor's first and last name, and the employee's salary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a self join on the same table to get the name of the Supervisor:

```
SELECT E1.Fname, E1.Lname, E2.Fname as SFname, E2.Lname as SLname, E1.Salary 
FROM EMPLOYEE E1
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE E2 ON E1.Super_ssn = E2.ssn
```

As you'll be joining the same table twice you need to give them different aliases.

I used a left join to include the supervisor at the very top too (as that employee won't have any super_ssn), if all employees has supervisors you can omit the`LEFT`to make it an`INNER`join.

If you want the name to be a string with the initial too you can use the `concat_ws()`function:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',Fname, Minit, Lname) AS EmpName
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa5970/2)